# Is there a callback in Tk for mouse hovering inside a widget?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a Tk window with several widgets that enable a user to select a geometric grid line for re-dimensioning. One of the widgets is a listbox selection, where each possible grid line to redimension is listed. When the mouse is hovering over a line in the listbox, I'd like to change the font of that text name for that grid line to **bold**, and send back a command to another package (Pointwise) to highlight the line in the display window of the Pointwise grid generation software. Does Tk offer such a callback? I see there are ways to detect when the mouse "Enters" and "Leaves" a widget, and if something is selected inside the widget, but hovering seems to be a vague construct. Is there a function similar to *curselection* to grab the text where the cursor is hovering over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to start with:

```
bind . <Motion> {puts [winfo containing {*}[winfo pointerxy .]]}
```

That is, if the mouse pointer moves within `.`, the path of the widget that contains the current mouse coordinates is printed.

Answer (score 0):

There are no mouse events when the mouse isn't moving. There are `<Enter>` events when the mouse first starts going over a widget, `<Leave>` events when the mouse ceases to be over a widget, and `<Motion>` events when the mouse moves over the widget. This means that your GUI controller code needs to do a little work to track what is going on, but this isn't usually a big problem. Motion events have several associated substitutions, but the most useful ones are `%x` and `%y` as those say where the mouse has moved to in widget-relative coordinates.

Be aware that you also get `<Motion>` events delivered to a widget if the user clicks down in that widget and then moves away; there is an automatic *grab* of (mouse-related) events while any mouse button is pressed. This sort of thing makes doing drag-and-drop within an application pretty trivial (you just use `winfo containing %X %Y` — those are capital letters so we're working with global coordinates — to find out where the mouse is *really* over to determine which widget is the target) but that's a rather more complicated topic once you get into dealing with all the fine details.